# Creating Open Graph Stories an share with android

Tags: android, facebook

i want to create an open graph stories to share image from my android application on facebook. i read the documentation but it's not very clear for me. i followed the document and i create an custom graph stories (visited a location). but i don't know how to use it. 
my application is about a nearbyme places. the user can select a url image to share on facebook.

i want to know should i use it like this or there is another step to make.

```
  ShareOpenGraphObject object = new ShareOpenGraphObject.Builder()
            .putString("og:type", "location")
            .putString("og:title", "Paris theatre")
            .putString("og:description", "This is a wonderful place.")
            .build();

    Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_android);  //just to test next it will be a url image

    SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder()
            .setBitmap(image)
            .setUserGenerated(true)
            .build();
    ShareOpenGraphAction action = new ShareOpenGraphAction.Builder()
            .setActionType("location.visited")
            .putObject("location", object)
            .putPhoto("photo",photo)
            .build();
    ShareOpenGraphContent content = new ShareOpenGraphContent.Builder()
            .setPreviewPropertyName("location")
            .setAction(action)
            .build();

    action.getPhoto("photo");
    shareDialog.show(content);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can upload photo to show in open graph story. You can only put url in the object, e.g.,

```
 ShareOpenGraphObject object = new ShareOpenGraphObject.Builder()
            .putString("og:type", "location")
            .putString("og:title", "Paris theatre")
            .putString("og:description", "This is a wonderful place.")
            .putString("og:image","<<image url>>")
            .build();
```

Comment: What are other types used other than "badge" with setPreviewPropertyName(...)?